# How to develop an efficient Beacon Network

Tags: android, algorithm, graph, neural-network, ibeacon

I'm working on ibeacon technology till now no issue while developing but now i'm concerned about the performance and cost factor. My task is to develop a network of beacons based on beacon range, proximity, accuracy. Obviously I've to use minimum number of beacon to cover the whole store.I know I've to develop some kind of graph algorithm to make neural network kind of structure.Please guide me if someone already achieve this or working on it or can give me some kind of reference to initiate.

Comment: Show us something what you have tried till not.

Comment: The number and placement of beacons can be done via a finding a circle cover for the polygon shapes of the places where beacon coverage is desired. This is NP-hard for an exact solution, but can be approximated well enough. With a variable floorplan, the min number of beacons will also be variable. Although if the exterior walls don't change, you could cover the entire area to give an upper limit on the number required. Not to mention obstructions could reduce the max range, increasing the number required or at least increasing the complexity of writing the algorithms (not the big O).

Comment: Hi @Nuclearman seems like you would need a ton of sensors. Would it not be better to grid/cluster?

Comment: yes but to create a grid i need to decide minimum no of beacons

Comment: The circle cover does give you the minimum number. Depending on how long the range is, there could be a ton. Simple grids don't yield optimum results.  The key question is if there needs to be 100% coverage of the floor plan or if it's acceptable to cover specific areas (which can be defined via polygons). Either way, circle/sphere (for the 3D case) cover yields optimum results, though difficult to compute. Even simple grids are fine for approximate solutions though, but the approximates can be rather rough with NP-complete/hard problems.

Answer (score 5):

This is less an algorithmic question than a practical one.  Ask yourself these questions:

1. What are my app's use cases for detecting beacons -- do I need to trigger different actions for different beacons at different spots in the store?
2. Do multiple different actions in (1) need to be triggered in the background?
3. Are any of my beacons USB/wall powered?  (If battery powered, somebody needs to change the batteries periodically.  If wall powered, placement points will be limited to where power is available.)
4. Are there walls, columns, stairs or other obstructions that interfere with signal propagation?

If the answer to the above questions are all no (very rare), and the  goal is simply coverage of the entire store, I would sim!ply do the following:

1. Get a floor plan of the store.
2. Measure the transmitter range of your beacons 40-50 meters typical.)
3. Plan to mount battery powered beacons on the ceiling whever you want.
4. Draw circles on your floor plan with the radius of the beacon transmitter range, and move around as needed to minimize the number of beacons used.

Be sure to take into account the constraints imposed by answering yes to any of the questions above and adjust accordingly.  In my experience, these are the main drivers of beacon placement.

Comment: thanks @davidyoung but floor plan is not fixed and can't solve my problem with hit and trail because i'm developing prototype for client and based on that extend this to real one where floor plan may vary. So i have to develop some thing which can be extends furthure according to requirement.

Comment: @davidgyoung you seem to be onto something, seems like common sense but there are a truck ton of issues/variables in this whole thing. I guess they are looking for a location agnostic solution but thats dependant on the hardware no?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can generate layout randomly for example 100000 times and than for each calculate becon overlaped surface and chose lowest.